# Unable to access Linked server tables via job in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, linked-server

I have a job which tries to access data from a remote server. I have created linked server which is connected successfully. When I try to access tables by directly running the query it works fine. But when I run same query via job it throws an error "login failed for user".

Job is assigned owner 'sa' and running with ssis proxy with sysadmin and public roles. In security tab of linked server properties I have no mappings and "be made using the login's current security context" selected.

I am not sure how should I correct it. If I should add mappings then what should be mapped? Please help me as I already spend whole day exploring possible options but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: SSIS package run from user with SQL or Windows authentication?

Comment: @Indian it runs under sql server authentication with usedid and password of sa.

Comment: And do `sa` has same password on linked server?

Comment: Yes sa has same password.. Ssis pakage has owner as sa but ssis package is running under another credentials with sysadmin and public roles.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter who is the owner of package. Only the user under whom the packet is launched is important.

- If this user is Windows (Windows domen) user, read this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580(v=sql.105).aspx).
- If your user is sql-user, check it password and permissions on linked server.
- If all from previous step are correct, try to add this user to mapping with checked `Impersonate` checkbox.

Comment: step in the job which is failing is basically executing an ssis package. In run as field i have "SSIS Proxy" which has credentials <domain_name>/Administrator. Now to these credentials, sysadmin and public roles are given. now in security of linked server i have added <domain_name>/Administrator in mapping with impersonate checked. This is current state and job is giving error Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY \ SYSTEM. "Login failed for user '<domainname>\ <server name> $'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 50000). The step failed."